# Is there any Built in function for PHP Application same as compile() in python?

Tags: php, python, apache, yii2

I am looking for the builtin function or any integrated way in Apache or Php with same working as compile() in Python  . for my PHP Application 
Is there any thing related to this ??

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is my first answer. :)

As of I know, PHP is an interpreted language in which only that executable file(php.exe in your php installation directory) is compiled and your code is only interpreted and no inbuilt functions like python.

If you still need compile as of in python, try [HHVM](http://hhvm.com/) a virtual machine

(never used that)

and there are some third party compilers like [ZZEE](http://www.zzee.com/phpexe/) which compiles into a GUI exe